# Create images for multiple screen resolutions

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I am designing a page for my app in which i am using two images and a few vertical textviews.  But when i am launching the app in the emulator using different resolutions, the images are getting distorted.  I used 9-patch.png but found out that it is deprecated from Android 3.0, can i use it if i am developing an app for 2.3 and above??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:background="#FFFFFF" android:orientation="horizontal">
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/auto" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="Home"  android:textColor="#FF0000" android:id="@+id/textView8" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text=">Products"  android:textColor="#FF0000" android:id="@+id/textView7" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:text="Replacement Parts" android:textColor="#000000" ></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:text="Accessories"       android:textColor="#000000" android:focusable="true"     android:layout_gravity="left" android:cursorVisible="true" ></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView6" android:text="Tools Equipment"   android:textColor="#000000" ></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:text="Fluids Chemicals"  android:textColor="#000000"  ></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView5" android:text="Performance"       android:textColor="#000000" android:onClick="Perform"    ></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/test_9patch_patched" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please let me know if there is any other way apart from 9-patch.png image...

Comment: Have you tried using weighting? Make sure you image is using the right scale type to...

Comment: Thanks alot guys...
I checked throughly the api once again and it seems 9 patch is not deprecated,but it got me thinking there are numerous android devices(Mobiles) of different screen sizes.so,what is the best practice used to adjust an image according to different screen sizes??

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read about 9-patch being deprecated in 3.0. Can you cite the source?

If you want to use different image sizes for different screens, you can follow this list
(I think the name explains for its usage):

```
drawable-hdpi
drawable-large-hdpi
drawable-large-ldpi
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-xhdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-normal-hdpi
drawable-normal-ldpi
drawable-normal-mdpi
drawable-normal-xhdpi
drawable-small-hdpi
drawable-small-ldpi
drawable-small-mdpi
drawable-small-xhdpi
drawable-v4
drawable-xlarge
drawable-xlarge-hdpi
drawable-xlarge-ldpi
drawable-xlarge-mdpi
drawable-xlarge-xhdpi
```

for layouts:

```
layout
layout-land
layout-land-ldpi
layout-ldpi
layout-xlarge-land-v11
layout-xlarge-v11
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make different pixels size image for various screen using photoshop or another image editing tool and put them in hdpi ,ldpi,and mdpi drawable folder .

System will automatically choose image according to resolution of device.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "can I use nine patch for 2.3 and above?" I would ask you "yes, indeed, I do it without issues". I didn't know it was deprecated since 3.0, unfortunately. I like this feature.

Comment: deprecated ? What replaces it ?